# Fix animated underline in header

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I need to fix my animated underline in my header.
 I want to **fasten it under the active page.** 
**Underline must come back everytime to the active page.**

**I'm adding also screenshots *(in first is what I have now and in the second is what i want to)*:**
https://gyazo.com/bf66aba84f4fef0440a11a85dcf83aed
https://gyazo.com/c6aa43d5e3ac4bf014e2216467f7ddac

There is where I inspired **(default code)**: [**Codepen.io**](https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon)

In the demo page you have also marked active underline position. I will add it down bellow. I did it with media queries.

**I'll be really glad if you help me with this.**

### **Thanks.**

---

**Style:**

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1530px) {
.header {background-size: auto 150%}
.aktivniopenz {margin-left: 8% !important}}

@media screen and (max-width: 1290px) {
.aktivniubytovani {margin-left: 27% !important}
.aktivnicenik {margin-left: 45% !important}
.aktivnifotogalerie {margin-left: 63.5% !important}}

@media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
.headertext {margin-right: auto;left: 0;margin-left: 355px}
.aktivniopenz {margin-left: 9% !important}
.aktivnicenik {margin-left: 45.5% !important}
.aktivnikontakt {margin-left: 82.5% !important}}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.aktivniubytovani {margin-left: 28% !important}
.aktivnicenik {margin-left: 46.5% !important}
.aktivnifotogalerie {margin-left: 64% !important}
.aktivnikontakt {margin-left: 83% !important}}

#container {
width: 100%;
margin: -60px auto ;
font-family: main2 !important;font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 3.5px; font-size: 1.1em;}

ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;}

.headeraa {
display: inline-block;
width: 19%;
padding: .75rem 0;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
color: #185fc1;}

.headeraa:hover {text-decoration: none !important;color: #1d87eb}

.one:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 2%;}

.two:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 21%;}

.three:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 41%;}

.four:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 60.5%;}

.five:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 80.5%;}

hr {height: .25rem  !important;
width: 15%;
margin: 0 0 0 2%;
background: tomato !important;
border: none;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
display: inline-block;}

@font-face {
font-family: main2;
src: url("fonty/main2.otf")}

.aktivniopenz {height: .24rem  !important;
           width: 10%;
           margin: 0 0 0 7%;margin-top: 21.5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px; 
               background: tomato !important;
               border: none;
               transition: none;
               display: inline-block;}

.aktivniubytovani {    height: .24rem  !important;
                   width: 10%;
                   margin: 0 0 0 26%;margin-top: 21.5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px; 
                   background: tomato !important;
                   border: none;
                   transition: none;
                   display: inline-block;}

.aktivnicenik {    height: .24rem  !important;
               width: 10%;
               margin: 0 0 0 44.6%;margin-top: 21.5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px; 
               background: tomato !important;
               border: none;
               transition: none;
               display: inline-block;}

.aktivnifotogalerie {    height: .24rem  !important;
                     width: 10%;
                     margin: 0 0 0 63%;margin-top: 21.5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px; 
                     background: tomato !important;
                     border: none;
                     transition: none;
                     display: inline-block;}

.aktivnikontakt {    height: .24rem  !important;
                 width: 10%;
                 margin: 0 0 0 82%;margin-top: 21.5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px; 
                 background: tomato !important;
                 border: none;
                 transition: none;
                 display: inline-block;}
```

---

**Header Code:**

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--spring navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" type="button">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
            <!--MALY NADPIS-->
            <span class="headertext2">Penzion Delta</span>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse  navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul>
                <li class="one">
                    <a href="index.html" class="openz headeraa">O PENZIONU</a>
                </li>

                <li class="two">
                    <a href="ubytovani.html" class="ubyt headeraa" style="color: #1d87eb !important;">UBYTOVÁNÍ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="three">
                    <a href="cenik.html" class="cen headeraa">CENÍK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="four">
                    <a href="fotogalerie.html" class="foto headeraa">FOTOGALERIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="five">
                    <a href="kontakt.html" class=" kontakt headeraa ">KONTAKT</a>
                </li>
                <hr />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" aktivniubytovani"></div>
```

Comment: I am preparing solution for you. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current structure I came up with this quick solution.

First,

```
.one-active {
   margin-left: 2%;
}

.two-active {
  margin-left: 21%;
}

.three-active {
  margin-left: 41%;
}

.four-active {
  margin-left: 60.5%;
}

.five-active {
  margin-left: 80.5%;
}
```

On each page add above classes to hr element.

index.html page add `<hr class="one-active" />`

ubytovani.html page add `<hr class="two-active" />`

cenik.html page add `<hr class="three-active" />`

fotogalerie.html page add `<hr class="for-active" />`

kontakt.html page add `<hr class="five-active" />`

This should work. If you find this solution helpful, let me know and mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works without any problem. :)